# C structs NxN intersection

Tags: c, struct

I have a script

```
a.h    
#include b.h    

typedef struct b B;
typedef struct a A;
struct a{
   a   val1;
   b   val2;
}
```

---

```
b.h    
#include a.h    

typedef struct b B;
typedef struct a A;
struct b{
   a   val1;
   b   val2;
}
```

how can I make this work?
I can create `val1` and give him `val1.val2=xx` but `val1.val2.val1=xx` or `val2.val1=xx` it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create a struct that contains a copy of itself.  That can't work.  What you can do is create a *pointer* to itself:

```
typedef struct b B;
typedef struct a A;
struct b{
   A   *val1;
   B   *val2;
};
```